# how to use vuechartkick in nuxt js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js, nuxt.js

I create vuechartkick plugin in /plugin/vue-chartkick.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Chartkick from 'vue-chartkick'
import Chart from 'chart.js'

Vue.use(Chartkick.use(Chart))
```

nuxt template

```
 <div class="pa-4 pa-md-8">
    <div class="border-light pa-4 pa-md-12">
       <line-chart legend="bottom" :data="series(resultSet)"> </line-chart>   
     </div>
  </div>
```

Then I add the file path inside the plugins key of our nuxt.config.js.

```
plugins: [ 
   '~/plugins/vue-chartkick.js', 

  ],
```

I received this error

```
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <line-chart> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option
```

But not working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Some plugins might work only in the browser because they lack SSR support.

`vue-chartkick` and `chart.js` cannot be run on server side, therefore you have to enable your custom plugin only on client side as follows:

```js
plugins: [
   { src: '~/plugins/vue-chartkick.js', mode: 'client' }, 
],
```

or by naming convention `*.client.js`:

```js
plugins: [ 
   '~/plugins/vue-chartkick.client.js',
],
```

See docs: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/plugins/#object-syntax

In addition, your component will be used to render a component only on client-side. So you have to use the `<client-only>` helper element in your Nuxt page as below:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <client-only placeholder="loading...">
      <your-chart-component>
    </client-only>
  </div>
</template>
```

To know more, see nuxt docs: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/nuxt-components#the-client-only-component

Comment: I followed this concept. but it is not working correctly.

Comment: @ImalshaRathnaweera can you edit your post to share your code about the chart usage in a nuxt page to reproduce your issue ?

Comment: @ImalshaRathnaweera did you use the `mode: 'client'` option in nuxt.config.js, and `<client-only>` element in your template ?

Comment: I applied nuxt.config.js and <client-only>. but not working

Comment: can you share a project (on github for eg.) to reproduce your issue?